# Minimum Random Variables and Integration

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

We are given a sequence of independent random variables $\lbrace X_{nk} \rbrace$, for $k=1,...,r_{n}$, with $E(X_{nk})=0$ and $\sigma^{2}_{nk}<\infty$.

My question involves a small piece of the proof the CLT for Triangle Arrays with Lindeberg Condition: For an arbitrary $\epsilon >0$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we consider:

$\int_{\Omega} \min\lbrace |tX_{nk}|^{2}, |tX_{nk}|^{3} \rbrace dP$

$=\int_{\lbrace |X_{nk}|>\epsilon \rbrace} \min\lbrace |tX_{nk}|^{2}, |tX_{nk}|^{3}dP + \int_{\lbrace |X_{nk}|\le \epsilon \rbrace} \min\lbrace |tX_{nk}|^{2}, |tX_{nk}|^{3}dP$

$\le \int_{\lbrace |X_{nk}|>\epsilon \rbrace}|tX_{nk}|^{2}dP + \int_{\lbrace |X_{nk}|\le \epsilon \rbrace} |tX_{nk}|^{3}dP$.

I don't understand the inequality in the last line. Can someone explain the jump from the second line to the third? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$\int_\Omega\min(Y,Z)dP=\int_A\min(Y,Z)dP+\int_{\Omega\setminus A}\min(Y,Z)dP\leqslant\int_AYdP+\int_{\Omega\setminus A}ZdP$$

Comment: Just saw your edit. Thank you Did! Does the inequality work though, because you are assuming that $Y$ is the smallest when integrating wrt $A$ and $Z$ is the smallest wrt $A^{c}$? What I mean is, how do we know $Y$ is the smallest in the first integral?

Comment: No assumption of the sort. An equivalent version is the pointwise inequality, valid on the whole set $\Omega$, $$\min(Y,Z)\leqslant Y\,\mathbf 1_A+Z\,\mathbf 1_{\Omega\setminus A}.$$

Comment: How would you prove that last inequality? Or, I should ask, is there a simple example where the inequality is strict?

Comment: ?? Hint: What does the inequality say when $\omega\in A$? What does the inequality say when $\omega\in\Omega\setminus A$?

Answer (score 1):

As Did said, it is a consequence of the inequality 
$$\int_\Omega\min(Y,Z)dP=\int_A\min(Y,Z)dP+\int_{\Omega\setminus A}\min(Y,Z)dP\leqslant\int_AYdP+\int_{\Omega\setminus A}ZdP$$
appplied with $Y=\left\lvert tX_{n,k}\right\rvert^2$, $Z =\left\lvert tX_{n,k}\right\rvert^3$ and $A=\left\{\left\lvert tX_{n,k}\right\rvert\gt\varepsilon\right\}$.